# Can I loop on each cell of a row without VBA in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet in the following format :

[image]

I want to have a second tab that uses this data and generates a table in this format
[image]

I was wondering if this can be done without VBA ? if not, any idea how should I best approach it ?

Thanks

Comment: I dont know if `TEXTJOIN` function could help.

Comment: Perhaps a pivot table will help? I have only touched on these, so can't provide a more specific example.

Comment: Do you have the option to rearrange your data? I am thinking three columns: "Functions", "Type" and "Category", where "Type" would contain "A". "B", "C" etc. and "Category" woudl contain "1", "2" ..."N". That woudl certainly make using a pivot table easier.

Comment: You may want to add `#PowerQuery` to your tags as it may be an alternative to `vba` to transform the data as desired. It is not necessary the same as "loop" but rather breaking the data down and put them back together in another way.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following named ranges:

- **Type_A** being all data in column Type_A;
- **Type_B** being all data in column Type_B;
- **Type_C** being all data in column Type_C;
- **Cat_1** being all data in column Category_1;
- **Cat_2** being all data in column Category_2;
- **Functions** being all data in column Functions.

[image: Result]

In cell `B8`, enter the following **array formula** (which needs to be confirmed by pressing **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** on your keyboard upon finishing the formula in the formula bar):

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,IF((INDIRECT(B$7)="X")*(INDIRECT($A8)="X"),Functions,""))
```

Then highlight the output table and click **Wrap Text** button under `Home` tab to display the outcome with line break within the cell.

**TEXTJOIN** function is only available in Excel 365 and later versions.

> A tip here, you can highlight your source table (including headers) and press **Ctrl+Shift+F3** on your key board to quickly set the column header (top row) as the **name** for each range. Then you just need to set up the first row and first column with all types and categories for your output table, and use the above formula to return the desired output.

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)